# Question about the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ is a random variable with binomial distribution parameters $n$ and $p_1$.

$Y$ is a random variable with binomial distribution parameters $n$ and $p_2$.

$p_1 < p_2$

How can I show that $P(X \leqslant k) \geqslant P(Y \leqslant k)$?

Please just give me a hint.

I tried comparing the terms ${n \choose k}p_1^k(1-p_1)^{n-k}$, but this doesn't work (after trying this, it's obvious in hindsight that it doesn't work.

Comment: (I haven't thought this through, but) perhaps induction on $k$ may work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** define the two variables on the same probability space. Specifically, let $X = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i$ and $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n B_i$, where $\{A_i\}$ and $\{B_i\}$ are each collections of independent Bernoulli variables. However, $A_i$ and $B_i$ should be *dependent* variables; specifically, they should each be defined on the common sample space $[0, 1]$ in the following way:
$$(A_i, B_i) \mapsto \begin{cases}
  (1, 1), & x < p_1\\
  (0, 1), & p_1 < x < p_2\\
  (0, 0), & x > p_2.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This looks like a multinomial distribution. Should I calculate P(X =< k) and P(Y =< k) based on this new random variable?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan : The point would be that when the random variables are defined in this way then the event $Y\le k$ can occur only when $X\le k$ occurs, and thus $\Pr(Y\le k) \le \Pr(X\le k).$ But if you have any random variables with the distributions you specify, then $\Pr(Y\le k)$ and $\Pr(X\le k)$ are still the same as what they are in this example.

Comment: It's not quite a multinomial distribution, because the way in which $X$ and $Y$ are interrelated does not quite fit the correct description. To complete the proof, you shouldn't have to "calculate" much else -- rather, explicitly consider the sample space (which is $[0, 1]^n$) and consider describing the subsets of the sample space on which $\{X \leq k\}$ and $\{Y \leq k\}$.

Comment: I think I get it now. I wonder if there is a less clever, way to do this? Is this a standard technique?

Comment: This is an example of the standard technique called "coupling": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much.